# How can i get "All files access" or "Permanent and complete access to a folder" in android 11 (Scoped Storage) with b4a?

Tags: android, android-10.0, basic4android, scoped-storage, android-11

Any sample please

Can all apps get "All files access"? (like apk files non-shared and out of play store?)

and after getting "All files access" or "access to a storage folder" can i use file addres like this

```
File.Combine(File.DirRootExternal,"mySelectedfolderOrAppFolder/subfolder/file.zip")
```

or

```
File.ListFiles()
```

and other File methods...?

what about android 10 ? should i use just `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
in manifest and its fine?`

Answer (score 0):

For accessing all files in android 10, for a specific folder you can use **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE**.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE